# XML code in a Box

Tags: listings

Here is a minimal version of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
morestring=[b]",
morestring=[s]{>}{<},
morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
stringstyle=\color{black},
identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}% list your attributes here
}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\lstset{language=XML}
\begin{lstlisting}

<balise1> 1 </balise1> 
<balise2> 2</balise2> 



\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

My question is: Please how can i set my XML code in a box and how can set a title to this box (i'd like to cite it in the text) ?

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Refer to §1.4 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Minimal example with citation and frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=tb,language=XML}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=Some caption,label=lst:ref]
<balise1> 1 </balise1>
<balise2> 2 </balise2>
\end{lstlisting}
Refer to Listing~\ref{lst:ref}.
\end{document}
```

More information can be found in §1.4 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: And many more features with `tcolorbox`

Comment: Ok :) Please, how can i add the option 'here' [H] ?[float=h] ? and how can i center text in the frame? Thanks a lot

Comment: @researcher For the first, just don't make it float. If it's an inline listing, explain it in the text (i.e. no caption). If you really want to know how to use `H` with this, read the manual. It's spelled out there. For the second, I legitimately don't know. As a `lstlisting`, I don't think it's really possible. I had a similar problem with my thesis. What I ended up doing was manually constructing the figure with boxes and a minipage, but this is quickly leaving the scope of this question. :) One of the many reasons we ask that posts ask only one question at a time. :)